# Problems with sound after running a video file (mp4, avi)

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have been experiencing issues with my audio. Everything was working fine until I opened a mp4-file with VLC and chose an audio device.

I'm new at Ubuntu, and though I read a bunch of pages online about the sound system on Linux/Ubuntu couldn't figure out the problem...

So, what happens is this.

1. After booting I can watch youtube videos without issues and running the command

   ```
   markus@markus-HP:~$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
   Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
   ```

makes Ubuntu say 'Front Center' with the above console output.

2. The system also detects two sound devices:

   ```
   markus@markus-HP:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
    0 [MID            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel MID HDA Intel MID at 0xc4500000 irq 29
    1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI HDA ATI HDMI at 0xc4420000 irq 30
   ```
3. But when attempting to play any .mp4 or .avi-file using either VLC or pre-installed video, the video application breaks down, plays the video without audio.
4. when trying to watch a youtube video firefox freezes or plays the video without sound. when attempting to change the audio volume Ubuntu doesn't respond or does with delay (after around 10 seconds).
5. also running the above 'Front_Center' command produces a different output.

   ```
   markus@markus-HP:~$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
   ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Timeout

   aplay: main:722: audio open error: Connection refused
   ```

I experienced with .asoundrc for a tiny bit, but deleted it again. I also removed pulseaudio, but reinstalled it again and now the following packages are installed

```
    markus@markus-HP:~$ apt --installed list
    pulseaudio/trusty-updates,now 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 amd64 [installed]
    pulseaudio-module-x11/trusty-updates,now 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    pulseaudio-utils/trusty-updates,now 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

...my guess is that I messed something up when choosing an option in VLC at audio device, but I couldn't figure out what exactly this affacted.

..I also tried to drop pulseaudio entirely and let ALSA do all the work, but I couldn't understand how to do this. The article I read was [this](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Sound_Problembehebung) (in german!), but I cannot find the Multimedia Systems Selector, nor do I know any other way to change all devices to ALSA...

best,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled Ubuntu and, at least, it's working again fine. Didn't figure out the problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

there is a setting in vlc that says encoder type
you can try the settings of this to see if any work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn1bt.png)